# What's the 'right' way for a superview to size its subview?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I just started contributing to an iOS project and noticed this recurring pattern:

```
// This takes place in the superview
// This is the first access of subviewController.view,
// so the subview controller will create its view
// Then we'll immediately resize it to our desired frame
subviewController.view.frame = CGMakeRect(x, y, width, height);
```

It seems odd/inefficient to me for the subview's controller to create the subview with a particular frame size only to have the superview immediately resize it.

Is there some other design pattern I'm missing that allows the superview to pass the desired size to the subview from the get-go, so this immediate resizing is unnecessary?

Obviously the subview controller could just have a special method on it that takes the size as a param, but I'm wondering if this is a kosher/common pattern or not.

Answer (score 1):

Where ever the subview is getting created, instead of creating with `init` method you can always create with `initWithFrame`. Btw, are we talking about a controller's main view? Then you can always set the view size from interface builder before compiling the project.

However, if the application needs the subview dynamically changed at every launch then the current way of doing it is the only option.

Comment: The subview is already using initWithFrame. The problem is that it doesn't know what its size should be; only the superview knows.

Comment: And these views are created programmatically so interface builder isn't in the picture.

Comment: And the the property you are passing inside CGMakeRect() are statically defined or it is being changed every single launch?

Comment: It's dynamic. But, there *are* other ways of doing this. After all, my subview controller object could have a special method that takes the desired size as input, rather than relying on the subviewController.view accessor to create the view. However, given that this isn't a standard method on UIViewController, my assumption is that setting the frame and then immediately resetting it isn't actually an important performance or code-cleanliness consideration. Just looking for verification of that.

Comment: Well, sometimes it depends try the other way around and see if there is any side effect. As you mentioned you have just joined this project so check the documentation if there is any warning mentioned and probably a justification of why they needed to do this way. If there is no justification and the other way around works! then you are 100% correct, setting view size and then resizing it is not good for performance.